# Simplifying a Javascript Statement

Tags: javascript

I'll just give you a quick idea of the setup before I ask the question:

I currently have a Stock Ordering System that has a list of products and next to each product is 3 divs, a number of many is to be ordered and a + Box and a - box which when clicked increase or decrease the number.

Currently, My Javascript is horrible (Eye Bleedingly so!) I have set the Javascript Code for each individual + & - Button Manually for every Product which just isn't feasible in the long run.

My Code for a single product is as follows

```
var largebeefburger = 0;
document.getElementById("largebeefburger").value = largebeefburger;
function largebeefburgerup(){
largebeefburger++
document.getElementById("largebeefburger").value = largebeefburger;
}
function largebeefburgerdown(){
 if (largebeefburger <= 0){document.getElementById("largebeefburger").value = largebeefburger;}
else {
largebeefburger--
document.getElementById("largebeefburger").value = largebeefburger;
  }}
```

As you can see this is completely unwieldy and is a nightmare to upgrade.

My Question is:

Is there a way to simplify this down to two functions for every single product? For example

productup
productdown

Changing the front end is not a problem at all, so If I need to move Divs around so the number becomes a parent of the the buttons that's absolutely fine.

Any help and advise would be greatly appreciated

Thank you.

EDIT (My Html)

```
<div class="productbox">Large Beef Burgers (Case)</div><div     onClick="largebeefburgerdown()" class="minus">-</div>
<div class="numberbox"><input name="largebeefburger" type="text" readonly   id="largebeefburger" value=""></div>
<div onClick="largebeefburgerup()" class="plus">+</div>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. But people will have to see your HTML to give you anything but a theoretical example.

Comment: FYI, if you want to ask about any possible issues with the question, the place to do that is http://meta.stackoverflow.com rather than putting something at the top of the question, where it interferes with how the question shows up in lists, etc. Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

- Based on the structure of the DOM you're manipulating
- Based on `data-*` attributes on elements
- Probably several others

The best way will depend on your HTML/DOM structure.

Here's an example that works by working within a surrounding element, using a delegated click handler on a container around all of them:

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var target, field, incr;
    
    target = e.target;
    if (target.className == "up") {           // See note below
      incr = 1;
    } else if (target.className == "down") {  // See note below
      incr = -1;
    }
    if (incr) {
      field = target.parentNode.querySelector("input[type=text]");
      field.value = +field.value + incr;
    }
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="up">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="down">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="up">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="down">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="up">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="down">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a structure that's more fragile because it relies on your updating a `data-*` attribute on the buttons when you change things:

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var target, fieldId, field, incr;
    
    target = e.target;
    fieldId = target.getAttribute("data-field");
    if (fieldId) {
      if (target.className == "up") {            // See note below
        incr = 1;
      } else if (target.className == "down") {   // See note below
        incr = -1;
      }
      if (incr) {
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId);
        if (field) {
          field.value = +field.value + incr;
        }
      }
    }
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="first" type="text" value="0">
  <input data-field="first" type="button" value="+" class="up">
  <input data-field="first" type="button" value="-" class="down">
  <br>
  <input id="second" type="text" value="0">
  <input data-field="second" type="button" value="+" class="up">
  <input data-field="second" type="button" value="-" class="down">
  <br>
  <input id="third" type="text" value="0">
  <input data-field="third" type="button" value="+" class="up">
  <input data-field="third" type="button" value="-" class="down">
</div>
```

(Obviously, using `className == "xxx"` is just for the purposes of demonstration and would break as soon as you added a second class to those elements, but you can handle the details there I'm sure...)

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for thank you very much for your help! I'll mark this as correct as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a more generic function to increment a specified target.

```
function incrementValue(targetID, increment){
  var target = document.getElementById(targetID);
  target.value += increment;
  if (target.value <= 0) {
    target.value = 0;
  }
}
```

You can then call this function by passing the target id and the value increment (1 or -1) to apply.

```
<div onClick="largebeefburgerup("largebeefburger", -1)" class="minus">-</div>
<div onClick="largebeefburgerup("largebeefburger", 1)" class="plus">+</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but would this solution not still require me to have an individual piece of code for every product?

Comment: This is a more cleaner solution!

Comment: @Klobleo, Calling the function on the onclick event is the only thing you'll have to do.

Comment: Apologies, I misinterpreted where the target Id was being set from this is a great answer, I'm going to keep the other marked as correct though, as it doesn't require me to set a unique variable for each + or -, Thank you very much for your time and explaining it to me.